# Online classes are/is not a good medium of education

Tags: singular-vs-plural

> 1. Online classes are not a good medium of education.
> 2. Online classes is not a good medium of education.

Given that this is the only context available. I don't know why but I think **#2** is correct in this case, since we are probably talking about the concept of “online classes”, but I am not sure since it could also be **#1** because of the fact that it has a plural noun, i.e., “online classes”. Which sentence is correct? Also if **#2** is correct, should we put **online classes** in inverted commas?

Comment: Classes are plural. The medium of online classes is singular. The second sentence needs to be rewritten.

Comment: Thank you @MichaelHarvey, which one is correct out of the two? And how can #2 be rewritten?

Answer (score 1):

The **#1** sentence is the right one, because ***classes*** are plural so you must use *ARE* .

If you want to use the **#2** sentence you need to rewrite your answer in the singular form:

> An *online class* is not a good medium of education.

And usually you use *inverted commas* for the direct speech so you don't need to use them in the second sentence

Hope this helped.